# Can R download text from inside this sort of web app?

Tags: r

Trying do download text as in company profiles from this website

http://www.evca.eu/about-evca/members/member-search/#lsearch

In the past I had good success with similar tasks using for example the XML package, but this won't work here because the data I am trying to grasp is inside some sort of dynamic and the single elements in the list don't have own URLs or something.
Unfortunately I don't know much about web-design, so I am not really sure how to address this. Any suggestions, it would really suck to do this manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download  Fiddler Web Debugger or some other similar tool. It places itself between your browser and web server, then you can see what is going on (also dynamic/AJAX communication).

Run it, go to the website you are trying to understand and execute actions you want to do automatically.

For example if you open http://www.evca.eu/about-evca/members/member-search/#lsearch, enter "a" in the search box and then choose "All" (to get all results), you will see in the Fiddler that browser opens http://www.evca.eu/umbraco/Surface/MemberSearchPage/HandleSearchForm?page=1&rpp=999999 URL and sends "Company=a&MemberType=&Country=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest".

You can do the same with R, parse the result, get some text, maybe some links to other stuff.

Below code in R will do the same as described above:

```
require('XML')
require(stringr)
library(httr)
r <- POST("http://www.evca.eu/umbraco/Surface/MemberSearchPage/HandleSearchForm?page=1&rpp=999999", 
          body = "Company=a&MemberType=&Country=&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest")
stop_for_status(r)
txt=content(r,"text")

library(stringr)
matches <- str_match_all(txt,"Full company details.*?</h2>")
# remove some rubish from match
companies=gsub("(Full company details)|\t|\n|\r|<[^>]+>",'',matches[[1]])
#remove trainling spaces
companies=gsub("^[ ]+",'',companies)
```

Result:

```
> length(companies)
[1] 1148
> head(companies)
     [,1]                                                             
[1,] "350 Investment Partners"                                        
[2,] "350 Investment Partners LLP"                                    
[3,] "360&#176; Capital Management SA"                                
[4,] "360&#176; Capital Partners France - Advisory Company"           
[5,] "360&#176; Capital Partners Italia - Advisory Company"           
[6,] "3i Deutschland Gesellschaft f&#252;r Industriebeteiligungen mbH"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much! That really made my day, especially the Fiddler tool was really helpful, will definitely continue to use that.